# xdg-open URL from text file

Tags: linux, bash, xdgutils

I have a python script that writes a url to a txt file every x minutes.

I'm looking to open this url on browser by xdg-open.

```
xdg-open /home/user/test.txt (opens the txt file)
xdg-open https://example.url (opens the url)
```

I've tried to combine cat command with xdg-open but didn't worked.

Is there any way i can get this done without a secondary script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try it with `xargs`:

url.txt:

```
https://google.com
https://github.com
```

Command:

```
< ~/url.txt xargs -I % xdg-open %
```